# jqGrid not exiting edit mode after saving (RESTful API)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid, jstree

I am working in the front-end of a page that contains two jqGrids. One of the grids works perfectly, it starts edit mode when a row is double-clicked, and exits edit mode after `Return` key is pressed to submit the changes. The other one (the one giving me trouble) is working and makes the proper POST request when pressing `Return`, but it stays in edit mode.

The strange thing is that both grids use the same code, only changing the `POST` parameters and the `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` URLs. I believe the problem relays in a function I use to convert the `POST` data to JSON format: if not all required parameters in this function are set, and therefore the server returns an error when trying to save, the grid exits edit mode. But when all parameters are set properly and the `POST` request is successful, the grid stays the same. The grid that works fine uses a very similar function to convert the POST data to JSON format.

Grid's (relevant) code:

```
function loadCommissions(userid, accountid) {
    $("#pager-commissions").empty();
    $("#jqgrid-commissions").empty().jqGrid({
        url : '/api/v1/commission/?account=' + accountid,
        datatype : 'json',
        ajaxGridOptions : {
            contentType : "application/json"
        },
        jsonReader : {
            repeatitems : false,
            id : "id"
        },
        colNames : ["Commission", "Type", "Rate"],
        colModel : [{
            name : 'Commission',
            width : 202
        }, {
            name : 'Type',
            edittype : 'select',
            formatter : 'select',
            editoptions : {
                value : 'F:Fixed Amount;P:Percentage'
            },
            stype : 'select'
        }, {
            name : 'Rate'
        }],
        cmTemplate : {
            editable : true,
            width : 100
        },
        ondblClickRow : function() {
            var rowid = $("#jqgrid-commissions").getGridParam('selrow');
            $('#jqgrid-commissions').jqGrid('editRow', rowid, {
                keys : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                url : '/api/v1/commission/' + encodeURIComponent(rowid) + '/',
                mtype : 'PUT'
            });
        },
        serializeRowData : function(data) {
            return serializeCommissionData(data, userid);
        },
        ajaxRowOptions : {
            contentType : "application/json"
        },
        autowidth : true,
        shrinkToFit : false,
        gridview : true,
        height : "auto",
        autoencode : true,
        loadonce : false,
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [10, 20, 30],
        pager : "#pager-commissions",
        viewrecords : true
    });
}
```

The function to convert the `POST` data to JSON format (expected by the server):

```
function serializeCommissionData(data, userid) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        user : '/api/v1/user/' + userid + '/',
        account : '/api/v1/account/' + $("a.jstree-clicked:first").parent().attr("id") + '/',
        Type : data.Type,
        Commission : data.Commission,
        Rate : data.Rate
    });
}
```

Retrieved JSON used by the grid (`/api/v1/commission/?account=1`):

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "commission_currency": null, 
      "account": "/api/v1/account/1/", 
      "Commission": "Test", 
      "Rate": "0", 
      "user": "/api/v1/user/1/", 
      "Type": "F", 
      "id": 5, 
      "resource_uri": "/api/v1/commission/5/"
    }
  ], 
  "meta": {
    "total_count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "records": 20, 
    "limit": 20, 
    "offset": 0, 
    "total": 1, 
    "page": 1, 
    "previous": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. On the grid's `PUT` request, the server was returning `HttpNoContent` (204), instead of `HttpResponse` (200). I changed the back-end to return 200 instead of 204, an that did the trick.